# Can i use Cloud hosting and CDN together?

Tags: cloud, cdn

I have a high traffic WordPress site i was thinking of moving to a cloud-based Cpanel. I wanted to know if I used a CDN as well, would this be redundant as far as site speed and performance.

Comment: CDNs are great if you have a ton of files that are constantly being requested. Although they are not necessary they will certainly not hurt your site speed in any way. They also protect you from downtimes on your own server. You can look into Cloudfare since it's free and pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

> would this be redundant as far as site speed and performance.

In my humble opionion, **no**

¿ Why ?

Imagine your Wordpress site is deployed on America, and someone in Asia is going to access it. If you have a CDN, the contents there (images, scripts, etc...) could be delivered by a closer node of the CDN in Asia or even it's own country, resulting in faster load times.

But optimizing your blog assets, size-wise or by any other means could be much more critical. If you have 1MB images, the impact of a faster response could be pointless given the download time.

Also having your Wordpress server only handling the "PHP side" of the work and not using compute or bandwith for serving asset's could allow for more request being handled concurrently.

Probably the are other important aspects i'm missing, i'll welcome any feedback on the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,It is possible and CDN is a DDos Protection
Which can be used with any server may it be VPS Dedicated or Cloud Server.